# Facebook SDK Javascript and PHP

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

So I'm creating an application within a the CodeIgniter framework that works as a points system with Facebook. It basically will give you points for sharing, liking etc. I'm using the PHP SDK for authentication and it works great but unfortunately the iframe method of liking and sharing won't work because I need to attach a Callback.

So I know there is the Javascript SDK which has the Like Button feature but can a callback be attached? And if so, can the Javascript and PHP SDK work together so you wouldn't need to authenticate twice? Or is there a way to accomplish all of this strictly with the PHP SDK? I really need to be able to like and attach a callback to it. Thanks!

edit: Attached Javascript SDK code

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '346032368781548', // App ID
      channelUrl : '//localhost/channel.html', // Channel File
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });

    // Additional initialization code here
  };

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   }(document));
</script>

<fb:like send="true" width="450" show_faces="true" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
        function(response) {
            alert('You liked the URL: ' + response);
            // Replace with the function that you want
        }
    );
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can run a callback via a second parameter, and if you use Facebook JavaScript SDK with PHP SDK, you shouldn't have any issues as long as the user is logged in and/or authorized. You have to, however add the Facebook Like button, and add this function like such:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
        function(response) {
            alert('You liked the URL: ' + response);
            // Replace with the function that you want
        }
    );
</script>
```

If you use [Facebook Ignited](http://github.com/deth4uall/Facebook-Ignited) it will allow you to easily integrate the Facebook PHP SDK with CodeIgniter. It also extends the functionality giving you easy to use functions.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! DO I still need to initialize the Javascript SDK like here? http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/#xfbml-methods  Currently I have it so they login to facebook and grant me access to their information. Then once they're authorized, I have a php print_r showing all the information. Is this PHP authorization sufficient for the javascript SDK like button that you shared above?

Comment: Yes, you will need to include all of the proper includes for JavaScript SDK in order for it to link the appropriate application id. As long as the PHP SDK and JavaScript SDK both have the same details then you should be fine. Once they authorize the app, you should be able to view their information yes.

Comment: Thanks again. I updated my post to include the Javascript code. I'm getting an error "FB is not defined" on the line "FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',". Any ideas?